# How to interract android applications with a raspberry PI ...?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi

I can program my Raspberry PI to control its GPIOs using Python or Wiring-PI C library.
I can control it with web interfaces like webiopi or web2py.

What I intend to do is write my own android app (layouts created by me only) and want this app to remotely acces the PI and run the code stored for the GPIOs control.

I want my Java code to control my C code remotely or something like that.

I have no idea what kind of libraries I need for this kind of interaction and I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: http://riverajefer.blogspot.com.co/2016/03/domotica-con-raspberry-pi-y-android-en.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can control your Raspberry Pi with web interfaces like webiopi or web2py, why not use REST API from your Android application.

[REST API Client Library for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444113/rest-api-client-library-for-android)

[Restful API service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197335/restful-api-service)

If you are looking for more ideas you may consider Bluetooth client server application with an Android client (on device) and Java/Python server (running on the pi)

[Initializing bluetooth connection android(client) to python(server) on pc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922319/initializing-bluetooth-connection-androidclient-to-pythonserver-on-pc)

Answer (score 3):

you'll need to setup a server on your raspeberry pi to receive GET or POST calls.

Then from your Android app use all the normal, standard Java to call this web service and get a suitable response, e.g. GPIO status.

for example android App use a GET request to `http://192.168.0.10:8080/GPIO/Toggle/3` your raspberry Pi server, listening to port 8080, will toggle GPIO 3 and reply back to Android 00001000 (meaning that GPIO 3 is On).

But that's just one possible idea, you could use a library like [Kryonet](https://code.google.com/p/kryonet/) to communicate over traditional sockets.