# Android to Raspberry connection

Tags: android, connection, raspberry-pi

How can I connect to Raspberry Pi and send information from Raspberry Pi to Android program.

I still don't know is there a function to do that or not.

could you help me please

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try installing [webiopi](https://code.google.com/p/webiopi/) and access its web-interface in any browser in Android or create a custom app.  WebioPi's web interface gives raspberry-pi's GPIO, console etc. You can, not only read the GPIO's but also modify them on the go. Further, you can also command the raspberry-pi to start some python script remotely.

See the architecture mentioned in the following wiki [link](https://code.google.com/p/webiopi/wiki/README)

Also see the following discussion on stackoverflow similar to yours: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069857/how-to-interract-android-applications-with-a-raspberry-pi?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You may use **Bluetooth** to communicate.

If you use Raspberry Pi 3 that means you have internal Bluetooth;

Please enter terminal:

> sudo apt-get install pi-bluetooth

If you have other Raspberry Pi types; get Bluetooth Hub first.

It'd be useful to read [here](http://blog.davidvassallo.me/2014/05/11/android-linux-raspberry-pi-bluetooth-communication/),
Also [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/robo-butler/bluetooth-setup/)